# Eclipse-based Custom Content Assistance? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

Is it possible to edit the content assistance of Eclipse? Sort of add rules or functions for it? I'm aware that Eclipse is open-sourced, but I was there an "easier way" or an interface?

For example, I'm working in Java 1.4.2, so I don't believe I have the magical "autoboxing"(am I correct in thinking that autoboxing would solve this issue?) . So when I'm working with getting parameters from a request, they all return strings when I may need a Long or an Int. I'm always interested in making things more automated (as any computer scientist usually would), so I was wondering if it was possible to have content assist suggest to use the common java parse functions (Integer.parseInt, Long.parseLong, etc) for the passed in parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to actually augment Content Assist in a highly detailed, customized way, you'd have to write a plugin. Eclipse is very well architected such that there are endless extension points via which plugins can extend base functionality, including Content Assist. But, writing one is not a trivial matter (though a skill that could serve you well, if you have the time to learn it).

Another option is to write your own Java editor template, which can emit any pre-defined snippet of code you want (including inserting parameter values), and will be included in Content Assist. Open Eclipse's Preferences and navigate to *Java* > *Editor* > *Templates*. You can use the ? help button on that Preferences page to learn more about them.